# Django class naming convention regarding abbreviations

Tags: django, naming-conventions

Is there an existing naming convention for using abbreviations in Django classes (e.g. models, forms, etc)? Specifically I'm interested if there's different rules between abbreviations/acronyms/initialisms?

So far I've only found examples of non-acronyms:

- `XMLField`
- `HTTPRequest`

What should a JSON field be called (since it's an acronym)?

- `JSONField`, or
- `JsonField`

Comment: And there are already [django-jsonfield](https://github.com/bradjasper/django-jsonfield) and [django-json-field](https://github.com/derek-schaefer/django-json-field). They both use `JSONField`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions):

Use `JSONField` over `JsonField`.

Since CapWords are used for class names, this comment applies:

> Note: When using abbreviations in CapWords, capitalize all the letters
>   of the abbreviation. Thus HTTPServerError is better than
>   HttpServerError.